# Drush silently fails to update core drupal 7 installation - why?

Tags: 7, drush, updating

For some reason, `drush` is reporting successful upgrade of a core Drupal installation from version `7.56` to `7.58`, however it is only partially doing the job! See below. Only updates a few files, should be a lot more than this as in all core `modules/` files, as a minimum, it should update the version number.

After this, if I run `drush status` again it gives an identical report, so after it has told me:

> Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.58.

I still see that we remain on `7.56`. Any ideas? I have ensured that there are `rwx` permissions for the user over the `Temporary file directory path` and `Drush temp directory` and tested this with running `touch` to test can create and read a file. How can I debug/resolve this issue?

[image]

Here is another run of the update with the `--verbose` flag (for more info), which renders the same result. Still, I can't spot an issue here.

```
[rootuser]:public_html$ drush pm-update drupal --verbose
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_XlJ3hK --database=myapp9name --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_anVSdw
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_bdl4sc --database=myapp9name --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_Jr6xnY
Loading release_info engine.                                                                   [notice]
Loading version_control engine.                                                                [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                                                                [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading update_status engine.                                                                  [notice]
/usr/bin/php /home/master/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php            [notice]
--backend=2 --verbose --root=/home/123456.myapps.com/myapp9name/public_html
--uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus drupal 2>&1
Update information last refreshed: Wed, 04/04/2018 - 13:38
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message                   
 Drupal  7.56               7.58              SECURITY UPDATE available 


Code updates will be made to drupal core.
WARNING:  Updating core will discard any modifications made to Drupal core files, most noteworthy among these are .htaccess and robots.txt.  If you have made any modifications to these files, please back them up before updating so that you can re-create your modifications in the updated version of the file.
Note: Updating core can potentially break your site. It is NOT recommended to update production sites without prior testing.

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Executing: svn info /home/123456.myapps.com/myapp9name/public_html/drupal-7.58
Executing: bzr root /home/123456.myapps.com/myapp9name/public_html/drupal-7.58
/home/master/.drush/cache/download/https---ftp.drupal.org-files-projects-drupal-7.58.tar.gz    [notice]
retrieved from cache.
Downloading drupal-7.58.tar.gz was successful.                                                 [notice]
Md5 checksum of drupal-7.58.tar.gz verified.                                                   [notice]
Executing: tar  -C /tmp/drush_tmp_1522848874_5ac4d46a6a4a4 -xzf drupal-7.58.tar.gz
Executing: tar -tzf drupal-7.58.tar.gz
Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.58.
Backups were saved into the directory                                                       [ok]
/home/master/drush-backups/myapp9name/20180404133418/drupal.
Command dispatch complete                                                                      [notice]
/usr/bin/php /home/master/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php            [notice]
--backend=2 --verbose --root=/home/123456.myapps.com/myapp9name/public_html
--uri=http://default  updatedb 2>&1
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_ewbZAj --database=myapp9name --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_KTg0dp
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_Shazn8 --database=myapp9name --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_RddgZd
No database updates required                                                                [success]
Command dispatch complete                                                                      [notice]
Command dispatch complete                                                                      [notice]
```

Comment: Try running drush with the `--verbose` flag so it gives you more info: `drush --verbose pm-update drupal`

Comment: @Beebee ah cheers for the tip, just updating answer with `--verbose` run, which has rendered the same result.

Comment: The only thing I can spot that's weird is the tar extract location `/tmp/drush_tmp_1522848874_5ac4d46a6a4a4`. I think that's where your Drupal 7.58 is. My drush (although very different version:5.8) on that same line shows the current drupal root folder instead of a temp folder.

Comment: Try installing a different drush version (maybe 7 or 6 or 5) and see if that changes the update behavior. If so I think it's just a buggy version of drush. To be fair though, you can just manually download and extract drupal 7.58 over your current install. It's important to get this tested and pushed live asap.

Comment: I have already applied highly critical patch SA-CORE-2018-002, but wanted to bring the core up to date anyway. I'm more concerned with why Drush is behaving like this.

Comment: @Beebee tried again with Drush `7.4.0` after clearing Drush cache - same result

Comment: The `--debug` option gives much more info than `--verbose`. Try it. You use Git to verify that things are changed, right? Have you checked manually that for example modules/node/node.info is unchanged? If it in fact is unchanged, what is the permission for the same example file (and parent directories) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `--debug`, yes manually inspected several files and git gave a faithful representation that these files were not being changed. Will look again at permissions. Thanks.